Localizing and consuming Angular 17 libraries
I am trying to define a simple procedure for localizing Angular 17 libraries and consuming them from their NPM package while still taking advantage of their localization.
The libraries are developed in their own testing workspace, which contains 1 consumer app and 2 libraries, generated via ng g library.
I am using ng-extract-i18n-merge to extract and merge localized messages, installed via ng add ng-extract-i18n-merge. The workspace already has @angular/localize (installed via ng add @angular/localize) and all the libraries are using i18n and $localize wherever required.
AFAIK, the main issue in localizing single Angular libraries is that extract tools work on a single, workspace-wide XLIFF file; they just scan all the projects in the workspace, and store the collected units there. Also, there is no easy way of knowing the source project of each unit in this file.
As a workaround, I decided to add a description to each unit equal to the name of the library it is in. Then, I wrote a simple tool to filter out all the units not belonging to a specific library.
At this point, I've temptatively defined this localization procedure:
(A) in the LIBRARY WORKSPACE:
(A1) run ng extract-i18n to extract and merge messages into src/locale/messages.xlf. This takes care of merging new entries into the existing messages, but it does not create distinct files for each library. To mark each entry as coming from a specific library, use a conventional description like e.g.:

i18n="auth-jwt-admin" in templates;
$localize with :description:message like in this example:

$localize`:auth-jwt-admin:message`;

This way, later you can split the unique file into smaller files and place each in the library package, so consumers of the library will be able to localize them.
(A2) translate the messages in each localized copy of the XLIFF file.
(A3) copy the files in locale to the src/locale folder of each library and remove from them all the entries not belonging to that library. You can do this manually, or use the above mentioned tool. This reads an XLIFF file and copies it into an output file where all the units not tagged with the specified description (or not having a description at all) have been removed.
(A4) ensure that your library ng-package.json includes in its assets these XLIFF files, e.g.:
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "assets": ["src/locale/*.xlf"],
  "dest": "../../../dist/myrmidon/auth-jwt-login",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}

Now, when you ng build your library the XLIFF files will be inside its dist folder under src/locale.
(A5) publish the NPM library, either locally (by publishing the tgz file) or to the NPM registry. I can confirm that the tgz file contains the message files as expected.
(B) in the CONSUMER APP:
(B1) ensure to install @angular/localize and ng-extract-i18n-merge as explained above, and of course the NPM package of the library created; also build all the libraries in that workspace if any.
(B2) run extract-i18n which builds the full, single messages file (one source-language version, plus one copy per locale). If I look at that file, I can see that it includes all the messages from the NPM package of my localized libraries, with their translations, like e.g. (here a message from a library named auth-jwt-login):
<trans-unit id="1446670643492611810" datatype="html">
  <source>Hide password</source>
  <target state="translated">Nascondi password</target>
  <note priority="1" from="description">auth-jwt-login</note>
</trans-unit>

(B3) configure the app for testing a specific locale: in angular.json, under projects/YOURPROJECT/architect/build/options add a localize property with the languages you want to build, e.g. "localize": ["it"].
If now build and serve, I expect the UI to be localized for Italian. This is true for all the messages found in my app's workspace, BUT none of the messages belonging to my NPM packaged library is localized, it is still in the default English language. Yet, the localized messages are there, and their IDs match the ones in the library's workspace messages.
Can anybody suggest a fix, or provide hints about building and consuming localized Angular applications using the standard i18n approach designed by Angular?
